# Eclipse RCP new plug-in dependency unresolved requirement

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, rcp

I am learning RCP plug-ins and trying to add another plug-in as a dependency. So I started with a simple HelloWorld application and tested and it works fine. Now I created another plug-in by importing external jar files and added that as dependent on my HelloWorld application. Now when I run the code I get the following error,

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2018-10-08 13:39:55.300
!MESSAGE Product com.be.tests.part1.product1 could not be found.

!ENTRY com.be.tests.part1 4 0 2018-10-08 13:39:55.315
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.be.tests.part1 [73]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: Part1Libs; bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

I have added the new plug-in (Part1Libs) in the dependencies tab. The 
MANIFEST.MF file shows the dependency as

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.intro,
org.eclipse.core.runtime,
org.eclipse.ui,
org.eclipse.equinox.ds,
org.eclipse.equinox.util,
org.eclipse.equinox.event,
Part1Libs;bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

It looks like I am missing a simple step but I can't figure out what is going on. Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: How are you running your RCP?

Comment: Running it from Product Testing (Overview Tab) -> Launch an Eclipse Application. I have also tried right clicking product and Run As -> Eclipse Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the 'Run > Run Configurations...' dialog and find your RCP.

On the 'Plug-ins' tab ensure that all the plugins in your RCP are listed.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Now I will try to see why export doesn't work but that is another question...